# Finding where program lives

Tags: applications, spotlight

I installed a program yesterday in a mess of terrible installation instructions and I have no idea where it lives.  I have files that default to opening that program, but that doesn't tell me where it is.  Spotlight Search returns nothing.  It doesn't appear to live in the Applications folder.  macOS 13.5.2 (22G91) obviously knows where it is, but I can't figure out how to get it to tell me.

Comment: Can you add the name of the program and a link to the installation instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and enter

```
find ~ -name "*xxx*" -print > /tmp/tmp
cat /tmp/tmp
```

where `xxx` is the name of the app (as appears in the menu bar when running).

If that doesn’t find it, change `~` to `/` and try again.

The redirection to a file is because [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102149) will flood the Terminal window with error messages, making it hard to find the answer.

Comment: This produced a surprising number of results and vomited out a lot of `find: /X/Y/Z/something: Permission denied` lines to my screen, but the /tmp/tmp file contained the information I needed to track down the application.

Comment: Instead of redirecting the matches, you could hide the errors by appending `2>/dev/null`, which redirects the [standard error stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) (which the shell calls stream 2) to the [bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device), leaving only the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) with the matches.

Answer (score 6):

Given you say files open with the program, open one of those files, which will open the program and add it to the Dock, so you can command-click the app in the Dock to reveal its location.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly faster invocation of `find` than the other answers posted that will only process **directories** named `*Foo*.app`, since a macOS app bundle is always a directory, and always has an `.app` extension.

```bash
find ~ -type d -iname "*NameOfMysteryApp*.app" 2>/dev/null
```

> *If that doesn't return any results, you can expand the search scope to the entire disk by changing `find ~` to `find /` (it will take longer to search)*

Another possibly useful tool is `mdfind` which uses the Spotlight database to instantly return results.

For example, if you know the partial name of the app, try:

```bash
mdfind 'kMDItemKind == Application && kMDItemDisplayName == "*Word.app"'
```

Output:

```
/Applications/Microsoft Word.app
```

Or, if you know the exact or a partial BundleID, you can try e.g.

```bash
mdfind 'kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == "com.microsoft*"'
```

Which will output something like:

```
/Applications/Microsoft Teams (work or school).app
/Applications/PowerShell.app
/Applications/Microsoft Word.app
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app
```